# Route [posts.index] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store my post but showing this error. But i have written route even so why showing error. I can't understand.

**Here is my code**

```
 public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)

    {
        
        $image = $request->image->store('posts');
        Post::create([

            'title'=>$request->title,
            'description'=>$request->description,
            'content'=>$request->content,
            'image'=>$image
        ]);

        session()->flash('success','Post created successfully');
        
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
        
    }
```

Comment: Could you also  share the code from your route?

Comment: Post your posts routes also from web.php.

Comment: Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('categories','CategoriesController');
Route::resource('post','PostController');

Comment: It's `'post.index'` ... or make your route `Route::resource('posts','PostController');`

Comment: its working thank you for your help